# Retrieving Landsat cloud percentage without downloading the data

Tags: python, landsat, metadata

Is there any way to get the cloud percentage information from metadata of Landsat data without downloading it? I would like a Python solution if one is available.

Comment: FME Server Demo > http://demos.fmeserver.com/landsat-sentinel-selector/ (not python though)

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280400/cloud-cover-percentage-in-google-earth-engine